# OMNeT++ make error in macOS (Catalina 10.15.5) for installation

Tags: qt, makefile, omnet++

I tried to compile source for OMNeT++ 5.6.2 in my computer (macOS Catalina 10.15.5).

But make some error during "make" command.

I don't know why occurs this error. I think the error is probably from "Qtenv" or "QT".

I also deleted "Command Line Tools" and reinstalled it, but the error still occurs.

Also I saw OMNeT++ installation guidebook that very simple step. This book description installation method by execute command "./configure" and "make" or "make -j4".

How to fix below error?

```
kimminwoo@Macbook-Pro-2020-13-inch-for-Minwoo omnetpp-5.6.2 % make
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -s MODE=release
***** Configuration: MODE=release, TOOLCHAIN_NAME=clang, LIB_SUFFIX=.dylib ****
===== Checking environment =====
===== Compiling utils ====
===== Compiling common ====
===== Compiling layout ====
===== Compiling eventlog ====
===== Compiling scave ====
===== Compiling nedxml ====
===== Compiling sim ====
===== Compiling envir ====
===== Compiling cmdenv ====
===== Compiling qtenv ====
animationcontrollerdialog.cc
In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:22:
In file included from ./qtutil.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/QTimer:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:106:50: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
                                                !QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, void>::Type
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};

In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:22:
In file included from ./qtutil.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/QTimer:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:113:50: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
                                                !QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, void>::Type
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};

In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:22:
In file included from ./qtutil.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/QTimer:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:121:50: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
                                                !QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, void>::Type
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};

In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:22:
In file included from ./qtutil.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/QTimer:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtCore/qtimer.h:128:50: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
                                                !QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value, void>::Type
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};

In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/QMenu:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qmenu.h:91:43: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
    inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<!QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};

In file included from animationcontrollerdialog.cc:20:
In file included from ./qtenv.h:33:
In file included from ./inspector.h:25:
In file included from /Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/QMenu:1:
/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/tools/macosx/include/QtWidgets/qmenu.h:119:43: error: no template named 'is_same' in namespace 'QtPrivate'; did you mean
      'std::is_same'?
    inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<!QtPrivate::is_same<const char*, Func1>::value
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:883:61: note: 'std::is_same' declared here
template <class _Tp, class _Up> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS is_same           : public false_type {};
                                                            ^
6 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [/Users/kimminwoo/Desktop/omnetpp-5.6.2/out/clang-release/src/qtenv/animationcontrollerdialog.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [qtenv] Error 2
make: *** [allmodes] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3):

I got some solution here this problem!

I had to big mistake because I did install "qt" from "homebrew" package manager.

So I did uninstall "qt" package by using "homebrew" and above problem was solved.

Hope it helps those who have the same problem as me!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of completely uninstalling *qt*, you can just unlink it:

```
brew unlink qt
```